# Como puede disminuir la cantidad de un campo de una columna en Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas, espero puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo un sistema en php y mysql de una escuela sobre inscripción, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: tengo un formulario de alumno donde coloca sus datos para registrarse luego de esto pasa al formulario curso donde tengo el nombre de curso y horario para que el usuario lo seleccione. **(aqui viene mi consulta)** como puedo hacer para que al momento de que un usuario seleccione un curso ejemplo guitarra este se reste en la tabla cursos? *ejemplo* si son 5 cupos y selecciona 1 que luego cuando venga otro usuario ya sean 4 cupos los que queda disponibles y se terminen los cupos no pueda registrarse en ese curso..

Anexo mi `tabla cursos`:

```
  id_curso varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  nombre_curso varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  fechafinal_curso` date NOT NULL,
  fechainicio_curso` date NOT NULL,
  `horainicio` time NOT NULL,
  `horafin` time NOT NULL,
  `AULA_id_aula` int(11) NOT NULL
```

y mi `tabla aula` ( que en este caso lo estoy colocando a ella quien tenga la capacidad) no se si lo estoy trabajando bien asi..

```
  id_aula` int(10) NOT NULL,
  capacidad_aula int(10) NOT NULL,
  estatus_aula varchar(20) NOT NULL
```

**Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No creo que esté bien ligar la capacidad de un curso a la tabla `aula`, porque eso no depende del aula, sino del curso. De hecho, un aula puede servir para varios cursos con diferentes capacidades y características. Recuerda que nuestros diseños deben corresponder a la realidad y ser lo más independientes posibles. Si tú ligas la capacidad de un aula al curso de guitarra, significa que ese aula servirá sólo para ese curso, lo cual normalmente no es así.

Yo imagino un diseño más o menos así.

#### `alumnos`

```
id_alumno
nombre_alumno
...otras columnas
```

#### `cursos`

```
id_curso
curso
id_grado
id_horario
total_admitido
...otras columnas
```

#### `alumnos_cursos`

Esta es una tabla asociativa para controlar cuántos y qué alumnos están inscritos en cada curso

```
id (autoincremental)
id_alumno
id_curso
```

#### `grados`

```
id_grado
grado
...otras columnas
```

#### `aulas`

```
id_aula
aula
lugar
capacidad_maxima
descripcion
...otras columnas
```

#### `cursos_aulas`

Esta tabla servirá para indicar en qué aula se impartirá cada curso. Puede ocurrir que en un aula con capacidad para 30 alumnos, impartas un curso con capacidad máxima para 10, por motivos de espacio, de características del aula, del curso, etc.

Los campos id_curso, id_aula constituirían un índice único para que no se repitan combinaciones id_curso, id_aula:

```
id (autoincremental)
id_curso
id_aula
```

Como puedes ver en el diseño, la cantidad máxima para un curso x estaría almacenada en el campo `total_admitido` de la tabla `cursos`. Si quieres presentar en cualquier formulario la cantidad de plazas disponibles lo podrías hacer restando el valor de `total_admitido` - `COUNT (id_curso) WHERE id_curso=?` en la tabla `alumnos_cursos`.

La tabla `alumnos_cursos` te serviría en efecto para saber cuántas inscripciones hay en cada curso, y también en qué cursos está inscrito cada alumno. Te serviría también para imprimir el horario de cada estudiante. O el horario de cada aula.

Es un diseño básico, el cual puedes extender luego para incluir por ejemplo calificaciones, profesores, etc, etc, etc. No es que tengas que hacerlo así, es sólo una idea, pensada de forma rápida :)

El diseño se puede (y debe) refinar todavía más para hacerlo totalmente independiente. Supongamos que para el año escolar 2017-2018 en el curso x se admiten sólo 15 alumnos, pero por cualquier motivo, para el año 2018-2019 se admiten 25 como máximo. Tendrías entonces que crear una tabla que ponga en relación los cursos y los años escolares, sacar la columna `total_admitido` de la tabla `cursos` y ponerla en esa nueva tabla:

#### `cursos_periodosescolares`

```
id_curso
id_periodo
total_admitido
```

Como ves, al diseñar la base de datos hay que pensar también en las posibles evoluciones que ésta pueda tener.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta probare con esto que me estas planteando, si, al principio tenia dudas si colocar la cantidad en aula

Comment: gracias por responder @cedano , una pregunta si en caso de que necesite los datos de un representante del alumno, para poder hacer luego el registro del alumno, en mysql tendria que hacer una relacion de 1 a N, la cedula del representante pasaria al alumno? estoy planteando bien esa parte?

Comment: @Lissi29 La relación puede ser uno a uno (1:1), uno a varios (1:N) o de varios a varios (N:N). ¿Cómo determinar la relación? **(1:1)** Si hay un sólo representante por alumno y un alumno no puede tener más de un representante, aquí la cédula del representante puede estar en la tabla alumnos... sigue...

Comment: **(1:N)** Si un alumno ha de tener un sólo representante pero un representante puede representar a varios alumnos, igualmente, la cédula del representante puede ir en la tabla alumnos; **(N:N)** si un alumno puede tener varios representantes y viceversa. En este último caso habría que implementar una tercera tabla que maneje las relaciones, dicha tabla tendría por cada fila una columna con el id del alumno y otra columna con la cédula del representante. (Es una tabla parecida a `alumnos_cursos` del ejemplo de arriba.)

Comment: gracias! por lo que me dices, es relacion (1:N) porque un representante puede tener a varios alumnos. @cedano gracias por responder

Comment: Es correcto @Lissi29, y la cédula del representante puede ir en la tabla `alumno` ya que, al no poder tener un alumno más de un representante, no hay riesgo de representantes duplicados por cada alumno. Si la respuesta ha respondido a tu duda inicial puedes marcarla como solución y si surgen nuevas preguntas en el camino puedes volver por aquí planteando tus dudas e indicando el código que está fallando. Saludos.

Comment: @cedano listo, trabajare en eso, por ahora coloque una llave foranea en alumno ( cedulaRepresentante) que me trae la cedula del representante

Comment: Vas por buen camino @Lissi29. Y si en un futuro el modelo evoluciona y resulta que el mismo alumno puede tener más de un representante, entonces tendrías que sacar la llave foránea `cedulaRepresentante` de la tabla `alumno` y colocarla en una tercera tabla llamada `alumnos_representantes` por ejemplo, la cual tendría además una columna `id_alumno`.